# Table Adapter Configuration Wizard from Oracle's Dev Tools for VS2017 can't parse || or (+)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, odp.net, .net-4.6

We are currently migrating our Oracle database from Oracle9i to Oracle18c (18.3.0.0). We have a C# .net windows form application that accesses the Oracle DB. I'm updating our .net application to use Oracle's new ODP.net managed driver which is installed with VS2017 Dev tools.

I have a custom table adapter that uses Oracle's concatenation operator || but when I try to modify the query via the table adapter configuration wizard, it throws as error saying it can't parse the '|'.

```sql
SELECT T1.TEXT || ' ' || T2.TEXT SOME_JOINED_TEXT
  FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
```

When I run my sql statement in Toad for Oracle 13.0 the statement runs as expected and includes the joined column. When the query is added to the table adapter configuration wizard it errors out on the ||.

I've even tried (to no avail):

- using the concat function but the wizard doesn't like that either.
- using a dummy SQL statement then going into the designer file and changing the generated SQL statement to the one I want. The GUI overrides these changes if a dev reviews the table adapter (which occurs when debugging).
- I've also put in a ticket with the Visual Studio Dev community, it's been "triaged", so time will tell what that really means.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: It's been forever since I used the GUI stuff, but is that wizard actually useful? You could just write a dummy query that coughs up a result set of the correct shape (`SELECT '' SOME_JOINED_TEXT`), find it back in the code (the wizard does nothing but generate some code/resources in the background) then change the query in the code (or resource/settings/wherever this ends up) to what it should be.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Yes, the GUI is very useful - when it works. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. The SQL statement is stored in the designer file, I can change it and save it, but if I view the original query in the table adapter (which is a common thing we devs do when debugging code), the designer file gets overwritten with whatever is in the table adapter (the dummy query as you suggested).